# Access split form datasheet goes off screen

Tags: ms-access

I have a split form and the datasheet part goes off the screen. How can I make the split form resize itself automatically so that all this blank space is not shown and only existing records show on the window?
[Here is a picture of the form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dni5F.png)
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, this is the normal behaviour of the datasheet. However, you can try this, it may fit your needs:

1) Drag and adjust the column headings to fill the white space to the right.

2) Set Gridlines to None.

3) Set Alternate Row Color to white.